# ERROR: module or package not found: esmf (missing __init__.py?)

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, init, lib

I followed the instructions to install xesmf (https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

```
conda create -n xesmf_env
conda activate xesmf_env
conda install -c conda-forge xesmf

conda install -c conda-forge dask netCDF4

conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib cartopy jupyterlab
```

All the libs were successfully installed. However, when I test it, it shows the error:

```
pip install pytest
pytest -v --pyargs xesmf
```

ERROR  - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ESMF'

So I tested only the esmf lib and it showed this error:

```
pytest -v --pyargs esmf
```

ERROR: module or package not found: esmf (missing **init**.py?)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be related to the issue raised in https://github.com/conda-forge/esmf-feedstock/issues/91.

The fix, as discussed [here](https://github.com/ks905383/xagg/issues/47) involves explicitly setting the path to the ESMFMKFILE before running python:

`export ESMFMKFILE=/path/to/anaconda3/envs/[envname]/lib/esmf.mk`

I also appreciate @masawdah 's suggestion from that [same thread](https://github.com/ks905383/xagg/issues/47) for a purely python fix.