# Install xesmf with poetry

Tags: geospatial, dependency-management, python-poetry, xesmf

With poetry manager I've created an environment with `xesmf` regridding package included.
However, simple `import xesmf` yields error `No module named 'ESMF'`.

[Relevant issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76931837/19224581) mentions way to solve it by setting ESMFMKFILE variable, but it doesn't work. The environment includes `xesmf` package but lacks depending on it `esmpy` package (and esmf.mk file as a sequence). Probably, poetry just skips it: asking `poetry add esmpy` explicitly returns `Could not find a matching version of package esmpy`. ESMpy is [available only through Conda](https://earthsystemmodeling.org/esmpy_doc/release/latest/html/install.html).

Summing all up, I want to stay with poetry, but still need working `xesmf`. Any way to solve it?